# Using OpenID access_token on a .NET Core API

Tags: authentication, .net-core, openid-connect, openid, webapi

I have an angular application that's authenticating users using OpenID, in which I have access to the access_token that should be used to authenticate against other services.

I'm currently using the Authetication Code flow of OAuth/OpenID

I am trying to use that access_token to authenticate users on a .NET Core Web API.
Whatever combination of settings I make here doesn't seem to get me any closer to the solution.

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddAuthentication(options =>
 {
     options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
 })
 .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
 .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
 {
     options.Authority = oauthOptions.Authority;
     options.ClientId = oauthOptions.ClientId;
     options.ClientSecret = oauthOptions.ClientSecret;

     options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
     options.UsePkce = true;
     options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
     options.SaveTokens = true;

     oauthOptions.Scopes.ForEach(scope => options.Scope.Add(scope));
 });
```

I appreciate any guidance/link on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case what you most likely need is JWT Bearer Authentication or a Token Introspection library which validates the access token against the Identity Provider.

For JWT, This is provided via the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` NuGet package and can be used like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://url.to.your/identity-provider";
        options.Audience = /* your expected audience - e.g. guid or resource */;
    });
```

This way you can get and update JWT Bearer access tokens in your SPA application and send authenticated requests to the API backend (using `Authorization: Bearer ...` headers).

If your identity provider uses reference tokens (i.e., they don't contain the authentication information but instead need to be used to get the authentication information from the identity provider), you will need to use token introspection. This is - for example - provided by third party libraries like [IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection)

Example for using `IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OAuth2IntrospectionDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOAuth2Introspection(options =>
    {
        options.Authority = "https://url.to.your/identity-provider";
        // Introspection requires client credentials to authenticate the requests
        options.ClientId = "client_id_for_introspection_endpoint";
        options.ClientSecret = "client_secret_for_introspection_endpoint";
    });
```

Comment: Hey Martin.. many thanks for the help. I have actually tried something similar, but what bothers me in this case is that the token I have doesn't seem to be a valid JWT (https://pastebin.com/b19CkxjR) .. hence, I get the Unauthorized response code.. Would you know what I could be missing?

Comment: If it's not a JWT token, you need to use token introspection - for this there is no in-box solution but community libraries (like https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore.OAuth2Introspection). please update the question accordingly if that is the case

Comment: Also I cannot access the past but suggest you check by pasting your access_token into https://jwt.io/ to find out if it is a valid JWT

Comment: You're a life saver! The library you recommended worked like a charm.. please post it on a separate comment so I can mark it as the final solution.

Comment: Updated the answer